# Enable d3 brush only for character key press?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, keyboard-events

I am trying to work with both d3 zoom and d3 brush on the same d3 chart. I would like to enable brush when 'B' key is held down on the keyboard, and disable brush otherwise. Accordingly, zoom will be the default functionality which would be disabled when 'B' key is held down on the keyboard.

I found a git issue [thread](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/issues/20) on d3 brush repo to make the exact same functionality work for 'Shift' key instead of 'B' key. While the solution available on that thread works for the 'Shift' key, I am unable to make the same approach work for 'B' key.

Implementation for 'B' key which doesn't work

```
  var time_brush = d3.brushX()
                    .filter(function(event) {
                      return event.keyCode == 66
                    })
                    .keyModifiers(false)
                    .extent([[0, 0],[time_line_chart_params.w, time_line_chart_params.h]])  
                    .on("end", setTimeRange);
```

```
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
              .scaleExtent([1,2])
              .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
              .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
              .filter(function(event) {
                return !(event.keyCode == 66)
              })
              .on("zoom", updateChart)
```

Implementation for 'Shift' key which works

```
  var time_brush = d3.brushX()
                    .filter(function(event) {
                      return event.shiftKey
                    })
                    .keyModifiers(false)
                    .extent([[0, 0],[time_line_chart_params.w, time_line_chart_params.h]])  
                    .on("end", setTimeRange);
```

```
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
              .scaleExtent([1,2])
              .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
              .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
              .filter(function(event) {
                return !event.shiftKey
              })
              .on("zoom", updateChart)
```

I also referred the options available to read keypress events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), and changed
`event.keyCode == 66`
to
`event.code == 'KeyB`
and also tried checking for event.type in addition to the key code as
`event.type == 'keydown' && event.keyCode == 66`
and
`event.type == 'keydown' && event.code == 'b'`
and
`event.type == 'keydown' && event.key == 'b'`

None of my attempts worked

Please help!

Comment: `event.keyCode` and `event.code` are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#instance_properties), you should use `event.key` instead.

Comment: I tried that too, it did not work. Updated post